# Selection Sort Not going through if statement

Tags: java

```
    public static void selectionSort(int[] list)
   {
      int comparisons = 0;
      int movements = 0;
      
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      
      for(int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++)
      {
         int currentMin = list[i];
         int currentMinIndex = i;
         for(int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++)
         {
            comparisons++;
            if(currentMin > list[j])
            {
               currentMin = list[j];
               currentMinIndex = j;
            }
         }
         System.out.print(currentMinIndex + " " + i);
         if(currentMinIndex != i)
         {
            list[currentMinIndex] = list[i];
            list[i] = currentMin;
            movements++;
         }
       }
     }
```

I have this selection sort but for some reason it is not going to the second if statement. How can I fix this selection sort so it works properly?

Comment: have you stepped through your program with the debugger?

Comment: Can you give the input that you are passing ?

Comment: It is a 50k element int array that I am passing @ShubhWIP

Comment: If your input is already sorted, then it will never go through the second if because the condition for it will never be true.

Comment: yes, I have @tgdavies

Comment: Why not arrange a test with a _somewhat smaller_ array, maybe 10 elements, that would be a lot easier to step through with the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Your selection sort logic seems okay to me. I think the only reason why your code is not going through second `if` statement is because your array is already sorted. I modified your code slightly to return `movements` variable with which we can know how many swaps were performed during the sort operation.

```java
public static int selectionSort(int[] list) {
    int movements = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
        int currentMin = list[i];
        int currentMinIndex = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
            if(currentMin > list[j]) {
                currentMin = list[j];
                currentMinIndex = j;
            }
        }
        if(currentMinIndex != i) {
            list[currentMinIndex] = list[i];
            list[i] = currentMin;
            movements++;
        }
    }
    return movements;
}
```

Then I tested this function with one non-sorted array and already sorted array:

```java
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30, 4, 50};
print(arr);
int nMovements = selectionSort(arr);
System.out.printf("movements : %d\n", nMovements);
print(arr);

System.out.println();
int[] arrSorted = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
print(arrSorted);
int nMovementsSorted = selectionSort(arrSorted);
System.out.printf("movements : %d\n", nMovementsSorted);
print(arrSorted);
```

If you can this code, you can see that no swaps were performed when sorting `arrSorted`:

```
 1  10  2  20  3  30  4  50 
movements : 4
 1  2  3  4  10  20  30  50 

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
movements : 0
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```